# How to find size of getline sentence?

Tags: c++, string, getline

I need to write some code which takes two sentences and compares their sizes.
In the debugger, the size of `sentence1` is `-858993460`. My question is, how can I find the sizes of both sentences? I can't use `std::cin::operator>>` because of spaces.

```
string sentence1, sentence2;
cout << "Write frist sentence: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, sentence1);
cout << "Write secound sentence: ";
getline(cin, sentence2);
int size = sentence1.size(); //the size is always wrong
/*if (sentence.length > sentence.length)
{
    size = sentence2.length;
}
cout << size;*/
```

Comment: "*I can't use std::string because of spaces*" - that is exactly why you *should* be using `std::string`.  `std::getline()` reads spaces.  In your example, you shouldn't be calling `cin.ignore()`, that is going to ignore the 1st character that the user types. Both `std::string::size()` and `std::string::length()` will return the proper number of characters that were read by `std::getline()`: `size = sentence1.length(); if (sentence2.length() > size) size = sentence2.length();`

Comment: @RemyLebeau your edit specifies `std::string`, but looking at the original, my guess is it might've just been a freudian slip on the part of OP when he meant `cin` (with the extraction operator). (after all, it seems he's clearly using std::string)

Comment: Post a complete program, a [MCVE].

Comment: @scohe001: more likely, the OP actually meant `operator>>` instead, which indeed does not read spaces

Comment: @Mercin: `-858993460` is `0xCCCCCCCC`, which is a possible indication of uninitialized memory.  Are you looking at the `size` variable in the debugger before it has been assigned a value?

Comment: I used the debugger wrong thanks for pointing this, i fixed the problem.

Comment: Good lesson in that. When you see a number you don't expect, convert it to hex or octal to see if it makes more sense.

Comment: Why the `cin.ignore()`? You did not use the extraction operator before, so there is no line break left in the stream.